# result.credit_card_verification is returning nil even on error in braintree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, payment-processing, braintree

I'm using braintree for payment processing and I'm trying to get [Processor Response Codes](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/reference/processor_responses) from Braintree with Ruby.

Here is my code :

```
 verification = result.credit_card_verification
 response_code = verification.try(:processor_response_code)
```

I'm getting verification as nil even when there is error.

Is there something else to get Processor Response Codes?

I got this code from [here](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/card_verifications/overview)

Here is my result.erros :

```
:errors: !ruby/object:Braintree::Errors
  errors: !ruby/object:Braintree::ValidationErrorCollection
    errors: []
    nested:
      :customer: !ruby/object:Braintree::ValidationErrorCollection
        errors: []
        nested:
          :credit_card: !ruby/object:Braintree::ValidationErrorCollection
            errors:
            - !ruby/object:Braintree::ValidationError
              code: '81707'
              attribute: cvv
              message: CVV must be 4 digits for American Express and 3 digits for
                other card types.
            - !ruby/object:Braintree::ValidationError
              code: '81713'
              attribute: expiration_year
              message: Expiration year is invalid.
            - !ruby/object:Braintree::ValidationError
              code: '81703'
              attribute: number
              message: Credit card type is not accepted by this merchant account.
            - !ruby/object:Braintree::ValidationError
              code: '81715'
              attribute: number
              message: Credit card number is invalid.
            nested:
              :billing_address: !ruby/object:Braintree::ValidationErrorCollection
                errors: []
                nested: {}
```

Comment: I work at Braintree. If you have a validation error, there won't be a verification. What does `result.errors` look like?

Comment: @agf I have updated my question. Actually I want to handle all the errors and show some generic message depending on the error types listed at Processor Response Codes. BTW  is it compulsory to display this validation errors first and after that manage Processor Response Codes?(Or you can say best practices)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you'd like more help than you can get here on Stack Overflow, please reach out to [our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Handling [Braintree result objects](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/transactions/result_handling) is progressive.

If `result.success?` is `false`, then you check for `result.errors`, which represent [validation errors](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/general/validation_errors).

If `result.errors` is `nil`, then the request was valid. In this case, you will have a `transaction` or `verification` object just as if `result.success?` was `true`.

You can then look  at the `result.verification`'s `status`, `processor_response_code`, `gateway_rejection_reason`, etc.

The linked documentation provides more details on handling error results.

Comment: And why not state that clearly in the dev docs on all sections??? Why does only the transaction section have an explanation?. If I do transactions it is stated how, but if I do vault stuff, there is nothing on handling results. On such a complex result object the doc readers can't assume it works the same way for transactions as it does for create_customer_data. Does it by the way?

Comment: Or the fact that you get an Braintree::AuthorizationError if you supply invalid params. The exeption name is not über clear.

Comment: @RutgerKarlsson The [verification docs also give this information](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/card_verifications/overview#verification_result_explanations), and yes, it is consistent for any object that can create a transaction / verification.