# credit card verification not working with braintree and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, braintree

I am trying to do card verification with the braintree api when I create a customer.  Here is the code that creates the customer:

```
@braintree_id = "#{current_user.profile_name}" + rand(5..1000).to_s
@result = Braintree::Customer.create(
    :id => @braintree_id,
    :first_name => employer_account_params[:first_name],
    :last_name => employer_account_params[:last_name],
    :company => employer_account_params[:company],
    :email => employer_account_params[:email],
    :phone => employer_account_params[:phone],
    :fax => employer_account_params[:fax],
    :website => employer_account_params[:website],
    :credit_card => {
        :number => employer_account_params[:credit_card][:number],
        :expiration_date => employer_account_params[:credit_card][:expiration_date],
        :billing_address => {
          :street_address => employer_account_params[:credit_card][:billing_address][:street_address],
          :extended_address => employer_account_params[:credit_card][:billing_address][:extended_address],
          :locality => employer_account_params[:credit_card][:billing_address][:locality],
          :region => employer_account_params[:credit_card][:billing_address][:region],
          :postal_code => employer_account_params[:credit_card][:billing_address][:postal_code],
          :country_code_alpha2 => employer_account_params[:credit_card][:billing_address][:country_code_alpha2]
        },
        :options => {
            :verify_card => true
            }
    }
)
puts 'result is ' + @result.inspect.to_s
@verification = @result.credit_card_verification
puts 'verification' + @verification.inspect.to_s
puts 'card results: ' + @verification.gateway_rejection_reason.to_s
```

The problem is that credit_card_verification is always nil, regardless of whether or not @result returns true or false.  Here is the console logs from the code above:

```
11:57:32 web.1  | result is #<Braintree::SuccessfulResult customer:#<Braintree::Customer id: "person2359", company: nil, email: nil, fax: nil, first_name: "sgdgsfd", last_name: nil, phone: nil, website: nil, created_at: 2014-04-29 15:57:32 UTC, updated_at: 2014-04-29 15:57:32 UTC, addresses: [#<Braintree::Address:0x007fe3639cefe8 @gateway=#<Braintree::Gateway:0x007fe364062eb8 @config=#<Braintree::Configuration:0x007fe3640630e8 @endpoint=nil, @environment=:sandbox, @public_key="vfyzr8zb7jqdhpxn", @private_key="[FILTERED]">>, @id="s7", @customer_id="person2359", @first_name=nil, @last_name=nil, @company=nil, @street_address="sdgfsgfgsdf", @extended_address=nil, @locality=nil, @region=nil, @postal_code=nil, @country_code_alpha2=nil, @country_code_alpha3=nil, @country_code_numeric=nil, @country_name=nil, @created_at=2014-04-29 15:57:32 UTC, @updated_at=2014-04-29 15:57:32 UTC>], credit_cards: [#<Braintree::CreditCard token: "66jz9r", billing_address: #<Braintree::Address:0x007fe3639cf8f8 @gateway=#<Braintree::Gateway:0x007fe364062eb8 @config=#<Braintree::Configuration:0x007fe3640630e8 @endpoint=nil, @environment=:sandbox, @public_key="vfyzr8zb7jqdhpxn", @private_key="[FILTERED]">>, @id="s7", @customer_id="person2359", @first_name=nil, @last_name=nil, @company=nil, @street_address="sdgfsgfgsdf", @extended_address=nil, @locality=nil, @region=nil, @postal_code=nil, @country_code_alpha2=nil, @country_code_alpha3=nil, @country_code_numeric=nil, @country_name=nil, @created_at=2014-04-29 15:57:32 UTC, @updated_at=2014-04-29 15:57:32 UTC>, bin: "411111", card_type: "Visa", cardholder_name: nil, created_at: 2014-04-29 15:57:32 UTC, customer_id: "person2359", expiration_month: "11", expiration_year: "2015", last_4: "1111", updated_at: 2014-04-29 15:57:32 UTC, prepaid: "Unknown", payroll: "Unknown", commercial: "Unknown", debit: "Unknown", durbin_regulated: "Unknown", healthcare: "Unknown", country_of_issuance: "Unknown", issuing_bank: "Unknown", image_url: "https://assets.braintreegateway.com/payment_method_logo/visa.png?environment=sandbox&merchant_id=b7gwpzqrspgmyc2x">]>>
11:57:32 web.1  | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 844ms
11:57:32 web.1  | 
11:57:32 web.1  | NoMethodError (undefined method `credit_card_verification' for #<Braintree::SuccessfulResult:0x007fe3639ce4d0>):
11:57:32 web.1  |   app/controllers/payments_controller.rb:210:in `create_employer_account'
11:57:32 web.1  | 
11:57:32 web.1  | 
11:57:32 web.1  |   Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@firehose/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.7ms)
11:57:32 web.1  |   Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@firehose/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.9ms)
11:57:32 web.1  |   Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@firehose/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
11:57:32 web.1  |   Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@firehose/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (16.2ms)
```

How do I make it so verification works?

Comment: You did notice that `@result` is an `ErrorResult`, which contain `errors`, which lists the verification problems found, right?

Comment: Yes, but that only contains errors regarding improper form submissions IE someone enters in a credit card number with the wrong amount of digits.  In the case that the form is submitted correctly, but the person's credit card for whatever reason is rejected, the braintree site says to use the credit_card_verification method i use above.  It says that here: https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/card_verifications/overview .  I will post my server logs in the case that proper information is entered in the form, in which case it is still not working like it is supposed to.

Comment: I just updated the code above

Comment: Have you checked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413961/result-credit-card-verification-is-returning-nil-even-on-error-in-braintree

Comment: Thanks, i looked at that, but i have the same problem even when i check with .nil? or switch to using transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Braintree will only run the verification if the passed parameters are valid, and only return the verification if it failed.

In your first example (now edited out of your post), the creation failed because you didn't pass valid parameters.

In your second example, the verification succeeded so it isn't returned.

You can simulate these different conditions in the Sandbox by using an invalid card number or one of the [Sandbox credit card numbers or unsuccessful verification numbers](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/reference/sandbox).

Example:

```
result = Braintree::Customer.create(  
  :credit_card => {                   
    :number => "4000111111111115",    
    :expiration_month => "10",        
    :expiration_year => "2014",       
    :cvv => "200",                    
    :options => {:verify_card => true}
  }                                   
)                                     

if result.success?
  # handle success
elsif result.credit_card_verification
  p verification.processor_response_code
  p verification.processor_response_text
else
  # use result.errors to see what part of the request was invalid
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  Do you know where in the documentation for ruby it says how to release only part of the funds that are in escrow, or should i contact support?

Comment: @Philip7899 You can't do partial refunds or partial releases on escrowed transactions.